# Change PHP URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess

I've been stuck on this forever. In order to change localhost/article.php?id=bryan to simply localhost/article/bryan or even localhost/bryan whatexact .htaccess code should I use?

Thanks guys, really appreciate all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will re-write `localhost/article.php?id=bryan` to `http://localhost/article/bryan`

Or you can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will re-write `localhost/article.php?id=bryan` to `http://localhost/bryan`

Comment: This still doesn't work since when I type in localhost/article/bryan it is giving me an internal server error.

Comment: Have you got re-write rules turned on? Your Apache configuration may not allow re-write rules. In your Apache config use the change the setting `AllowOverride` to `AllowOverride all`

Comment: Yes, I've got everything turned on since I wrote code earlier to negate .php extensions.

Comment: What type of server are you using? Can you post the HTTP server log? I have tested the RewriteRule at [htaccess tester](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) and it seems to work pretty well.

Comment: I have tested the RewriteRule on my Apache server and it works fine. Maybe you have not enabled mod_write?

Comment: This is the exact code I'm using right now: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Removes the .php extension from pages
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule (.*) $1.php [L]

# Cleans up the PHP URL of all pages on website
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]*)$ /article.php?id=$1 [L]